# Hibernate onetoone Annotation with the same entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, one-to-one

I would like to correct my code that is basically annotating a User entity  with itself using onetoone Hibernate annotation.

A user can be "Administrator" or "Patient" or "docteur".

i would like to add a column in the USER table that contains the doctor id. whenever a patient is created, he/she will have automatically one doctor that is linked to it.

here is what i did :

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "SSO_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String ssoId;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false)
private String password;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", nullable = false)
private String firstName;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "LAST_NAME", nullable = false)
private String lastName;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = false)
private String email;

@Column(name = "DTCREATION", nullable = true)
private String dateCreation;

@Column(name = "JJCREATION", nullable = true)
private String jjCreation;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient")
private Set<Consultation> consultations = new HashSet<Consultation>(0);

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id",nullable=true)
private User docteur;

public Set<Consultation> getConsultations() {
    return this.consultations;
}

public String getJjCreation() {
    return jjCreation;
}

public void setJjCreation(String jjCreation) {
    this.jjCreation = jjCreation;
}

@Column(name = "MMCREATION", nullable = true)
private String mmCreation;

public String getMmCreation() {
    return mmCreation;
}

public void setMmCreation(String mmCreation) {
    this.mmCreation = mmCreation;
}

@Column(name = "YYCREATION", nullable = true)
private String aaCreation;

public String getAaCreation() {
    return aaCreation;
}

public void setAaCreation(String aaCreation) {
    this.aaCreation = aaCreation;
}

public String getDateCreation() {
    return dateCreation;
}

public void setDateCreation(String dateCreation) {
    this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
}

@NotEmpty
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "USER_USER_PROFILE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "USER_PROFILE_ID") })
private Set<UserProfile> userProfiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>();

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSsoId() {
    return ssoId;
}

public void setSsoId(String ssoId) {
    this.ssoId = ssoId;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public Set<UserProfile> getUserProfiles() {
    return userProfiles;
}

public void setUserProfiles(Set<UserProfile> userProfiles) {
    this.userProfiles = userProfiles;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((ssoId == null) ? 0 : ssoId.hashCode());
    return result;
}

public User getDocteur() {
    return docteur;
}

public void setDocteur(User docteur) {
    this.docteur = docteur;
}

public void setConsultations(Set<Consultation> consultations) {
    this.consultations = consultations;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof User))
        return false;
    User other = (User) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    if (ssoId == null) {
        if (other.ssoId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!ssoId.equals(other.ssoId))
        return false;
    return true;
}

/*
 * DO-NOT-INCLUDE passwords in toString function. It is done here just for
 * convenience purpose.
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User [id=" + id + ", ssoId=" + ssoId + ", password=" + password + ", firstName=" + firstName
            + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
}
```

and here is a part of my view :

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="user"
                                class="form-horizontal">
                                <form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id" />

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="firstName">Prénom</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-7">
                                            <form:input type="text" path="firstName" id="firstName"
                                                class="form-control input-sm" />
                                            <div class="has-error">
                                                <form:errors path="firstName" class="help-inline" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="lastName">Nom
                                            de famille</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-7">
                                            <form:input type="text" path="lastName" id="lastName"
                                                class="form-control input-sm" />
                                            <div class="has-error">
                                                <form:errors path="lastName" class="help-inline" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="ssoId">Nom
                                            d'utilisateur</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-7">
                                            <c:choose>
                                                <c:when test="${edit}">
                                                    <form:input type="text" path="ssoId" id="ssoId"
                                                        class="form-control input-sm" disabled="true" />
                                                </c:when>
                                                <c:otherwise>
                                                    <form:input type="text" path="ssoId" id="ssoId"
                                                        class="form-control input-sm" />
                                                    <div class="has-error">
                                                        <form:errors path="ssoId" class="help-inline" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </c:otherwise>
                                            </c:choose>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="password">Mot
                                            de passe</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-7">
                                            <form:input type="password" path="password" id="password"
                                                class="form-control input-sm" />
                                            <div class="has-error">
                                                <form:errors path="password" class="help-inline" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="email">Email</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-7">
                                            <form:input type="email" path="email" id="email"
                                                class="form-control input-sm" />
                                            <div class="has-error">
                                                <form:errors path="email" class="help-inline" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="userProfiles">Roles</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-7">
                                            <form:select path="userProfiles" items="${roles}"
                                                multiple="false" itemValue="id" itemLabel="type"
                                                class="form-control input-sm" onchange="getvaleur(this)" />
                                            <div class="has-error">
                                                <form:errors path="userProfiles" class="help-inline" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div id="acacher" class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="docteur">Docteur</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-7">
                                            <form:select path="docteur" items="${docteurs}"
                                                multiple="false" itemValue="id" itemLabel="ssoId"
                                                class="form-control input-sm" />
                                            <div class="has-error">
                                                <form:errors path="docteur" class="help-inline" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                    <c:choose>
                                        <c:when test="${edit}">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Modifier"
                                                class="btn btn-success btn-sm" />
                                            <a href="<c:url value='/list' />"
                                                class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Annuler</a>
                                        </c:when>
                                        <c:otherwise>
                                            <input type="submit" value="Inscription"
                                                class="btn btn-success btn-sm" />
                                            <a href="<c:url value='/list' />"
                                                class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Annuler</a>
                                        </c:otherwise>
                                    </c:choose>
                                </div>
                            </form:form>
```

and finally the saveuser method in my service :

```
public void saveUser(User user) {
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        String dateCreation = df.format(today);

        user.setDateCreation(dateCreation);
        user.setJjCreation(dateCreation.substring(0, 2));
        user.setMmCreation(dateCreation.substring(3, 5));
        user.setAaCreation(dateCreation.substring(6, 10));

        Set<UserProfile> c = user.getUserProfiles();

        Iterator<UserProfile> iter = c.iterator();

        String first = iter.next().getType();

        if (first.equals("PATIENT")) {
            user.setDocteur(user.getDocteur());

        }else{
            user.setDocteur(null);
        }
        dao.save(user);
    }
```

is this the right way to do the @onetomany annotation ? how can i do this the best way ?

## UPDATE NR 1

#

i have updated my code by creating patient and doctor classes that are subclasses of the user class and i am having the following error :

> SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.vivalio.springmvc.converter.RoleToUserProfileConverter com.vivalio.springmvc.configuration.AppConfig.roleToUserProfileConverter; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleToUserProfileConverter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.vivalio.springmvc.service.UserProfileService com.vivalio.springmvc.converter.RoleToUserProfileConverter.userProfileService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.vivalio.springmvc.dao.UserProfileDao com.vivalio.springmvc.service.UserProfileServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.vivalio.springmvc.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/vivalio/springmvc/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:697)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:526)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4733)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5197)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>       at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>       at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.vivalio.springmvc.converter.RoleToUserProfileConverter com.vivalio.springmvc.configuration.AppConfig.roleToUserProfileConverter; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleToUserProfileConverter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.vivalio.springmvc.service.UserProfileService com.vivalio.springmvc.converter.RoleToUserProfileConverter.userProfileService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.vivalio.springmvc.dao.UserProfileDao com.vivalio.springmvc.service.UserProfileServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.vivalio.springmvc.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/vivalio/springmvc/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
>       ... 51 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleToUserProfileConverter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.vivalio.springmvc.service.UserProfileService com.vivalio.springmvc.converter.RoleToUserProfileConverter.userProfileService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.vivalio.springmvc.dao.UserProfileDao com.vivalio.springmvc.service.UserProfileServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.vivalio.springmvc.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/vivalio/springmvc/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
>       ... 53 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.vivalio.springmvc.service.UserProfileService com.vivalio.springmvc.converter.RoleToUserProfileConverter.userProfileService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.vivalio.springmvc.dao.UserProfileDao com.vivalio.springmvc.service.UserProfileServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.vivalio.springmvc.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/vivalio/springmvc/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass
>       at

Comment: I would be hesitant to try to do this manually with a single user class. I would provide two roles (user, admin) and two distinct `Patient`, `Doctor` user classes with inheritance. Each would have their additional members and doctor-patient relationships. You can still force it to be single table and let hibernate manage it.

Comment: There is ample documentation for how to put `@OneToOne` and `@OneToMany` annotations. You don't present any "problem", consequently you should rewrite your "question" to define what the problem is